# VBA replace everything in sheet except first rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a working VBA script which currently replaces all dots by commas (posted below). However I would the script avoid the first two rows and change everything else. What would be the best and easiest way to do this? I have only found solutions where you have to set a range and but I want it to work for all excel sheets regardless of the number of rows or columns.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Cells.Replace what:=".", Replacement:=",", _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Comment: Change `Cells.` to `Range("3:1040000").`

Comment: Why does having to set a range prevent you from doing this?

Comment: If you don't want to set the range you could use `Cells.Resize(Rows.Count - 2).Offset(2).Replace...`

Comment: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: `With ActiveSheet.UsedRange : .Offset(2).Replace.... : End With`

Answer (score 0):

You can still use range, but generate it dynamically: use the macro recorder and see what it gives you if you select all cells with the Select All button at the top left corner, then hold down CTRL and unselect by clicking the row headers.
After having a selected range, you can use [Application.Selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.selection) instead of Cells.

Comment: As Peh said in his comment.  Much better to avoid `Select`, `Selection`, `Active`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook this is absolutely just a starter, the generated code needs to be changed as necessary, it is a solution that does not start from scratch - also not optimal.

Answer (score 0):

```
set wsCSV = ... (your csv worksheet)
set rng = wsCSV.UsedRange
set ws = ... (your worksheet)
ws.UsedRange.Offset(1).ClearContents()
ws.Range("A2").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Values = rng.Values
```